# PHPBB forums clear cache manually

Tags: php, caching, phpbb, phpbb3

I use phpbb3 forums, and run a daily php script on the db server for updating user's permissions .

After running the script I found that only after clearing the cache manually from the admin panel,

I can see the changes in the forum website.

Where can I find the clear cache function in the servers library so I can add it to the automatic script?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where I pulled this from, but I have been using it for a long time. Place this in your `phpbb3` root directory, and name it something unique. You want to do this, otherwise anyone visiting the URL can clear your cache.

If you want to put this into your own script, I suggest looking at the `delete_cache` function, below for an idea of how it is done.

```
<?php
/**
*
* @package phpBB3
* @copyright (c) 2009 3Di - delete_cache.php v. 0001 - 2009-2-28
* @license http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
*
*/

/**
*/

/**
* @ignore
*/
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management
$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();

// Purges the tmp cache files based on time-frame
function delete_cache()
{
    global $phpbb_root_path;

    $phpbb_cache = ($phpbb_root_path . 'cache');

    // time in seconds the files are allowed to last into the cache dir
    $seconds_old = 1;

    // directory check-in first
    if (is_dir("$phpbb_cache")) 
    {
        $handle=opendir($phpbb_cache); 

        while (false!==($tmp_phpbb_cache_files = readdir($handle)))
        {
            // we delete everything but index.htm, .htaccess and sub-folders
            if ($tmp_phpbb_cache_files != "." && $tmp_phpbb_cache_files != ".." && $tmp_phpbb_cache_files != "index.htm" && $tmp_phpbb_cache_files != ".htaccess")
            {
                $diff = (time() - filectime("$phpbb_cache/$tmp_phpbb_cache_files"));
                if ($diff > $seconds_old)
                {
                    unlink("$phpbb_cache/$tmp_phpbb_cache_files");
                }
            } 
        }
        closedir($handle); 
    }
    // that should never happen..
    else
    {
        trigger_error('CACHE_DIR_ERROR');
    }
}

delete_cache();

?>
```

Comment: This code is working great if you'd like to delete some files based on age but to name it something unique isn't the only thing you should do, some hackers use directory scanners etc. Use .htaccess to protect this file against them, allow it from your server IP and your static IP (IP you're using to connect with the Internet) only. this could help you to make it more secure. I hope this comment is helpful to stackoverflow users